# Making many shapes on tkinter canvas that can be modified later

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make some geometric units and repeat them like 100 times on my canvas. However, I need to be able to modify each unit after they are drawn.

I thought to wrap the code to draw the unit (4 arc right now) into a single method and call that method many times. But then I can't access the first arc, etc.

```
def box(coords):
    arc_one = canvas.create_arc(coords, start=0, extent=90, outline="white", style="arc", tag=1)

    arc_two = canvas.create_arc(coords, start=90, extent=90, outline="white", style="arc", tag=2)

    arc_three = canvas.create_arc(coords, start=180, extent=90, outline="white", style="arc", tag=3)

    arc_four = canvas.create_arc(coords, start=270, extent=90, outline="white", style="arc", tag=4)
```

^ idea but then I can't access `arc_one` later

Currently I have:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=200, bg='black')
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

# direction will be dynamic later
direction='RIGHT'

# motion will be dynamic later
motion='FULLMOON'

# each bounding box is 100 x 100
# coordinates are (x,y) of upper left corner, and then (x,y) of lower left corner

coords = (100, 50, 200, 150)

# use box width to later move around
box_width = coords[2] - coords[0]

# use arc width for width of 1 component
# 4 components in 1 box
arc_width = box_width/2

arc_one = canvas.create_arc(coords, start=0, extent=90, outline="white", style="arc",tag=1)

arc_two = canvas.create_arc(coords, start=90, extent=90, outline="white", style="arc",tag=2)

arc_three = canvas.create_arc(coords, start=180, extent=90, outline="white", style="arc",tag=3)

arc_four = canvas.create_arc(coords, start=270, extent=90, outline="white", style="arc",tag=4)

'''
I want to just bundle arcs one to four into a single method, and call it with new coordinates to create many new 
circles. 

However, I won't be able to call each arc later if I do so.
'''

# second bounding box to the right
coords_2 = (100 + 100, 50, 200 + 100, 150)

arc_five = canvas.create_arc(coords_2, start=0, extent=90, outline="white", style="arc",tag=1)

arc_six = canvas.create_arc(coords_2, start=90, extent=90, outline="white", style="arc",tag=2)

arc_seven = canvas.create_arc(coords_2, start=180, extent=90, outline="white", style="arc",tag=3)

arc_eight = canvas.create_arc(coords_2, start=270, extent=90, outline="white", style="arc",tag=4)


def bold(event):
    id = event.widget.find_closest(event.x,event.y)[0]
    canvas.itemconfigure(id,width=2.5)
    canvas.update()
    time.sleep(.5)

    if direction == 'RIGHT' and motion == 'FULLMOON':
#         while there are no more new widgets
        while (id != event.widget.find_closest(event.x + arc_width, event.y)[0]):
    #         move cursor to the right
            event.x += arc_width
            id = event.widget.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
            canvas.itemconfigure(id, width=2.5)
            canvas.update()
            time.sleep(.5)


canvas.tag_bind(arc_one,"<Button-1>", bold)
canvas.tag_bind(arc_two,"<Button-1>", bold)
canvas.tag_bind(arc_three,"<Button-1>", bold)
canvas.tag_bind(arc_four,"<Button-1>", bold)

canvas.tag_bind(arc_five,"<Button-1>", bold)
canvas.tag_bind(arc_six,"<Button-1>", bold)
canvas.tag_bind(arc_seven,"<Button-1>", bold)
canvas.tag_bind(arc_eight,"<Button-1>", bold)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you think about [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend changing `box` into a class. That will make it much easier to treat each "box" as an object, and each object will have a namespace for keeping its own metadata. This is precisely the type of problem classes are designed to solve.

In the following example, each arc in the "box" gets two tags. One is `"arc"` in case you want to be able to change all arcs of all boxes at once, and one is a tag unique to each box, for configuring all of the arcs at once for a single box.

In addition, the canvas ids of each individual arc are saved in an array. With that, you can configure any single arc of any single "box".

```
class Box():
    def __init__(self, canvas, coords):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.tag = "box-{}".format(id(self))
        tags = ("arc", self.tag)
        self.arcs = [
            canvas.create_arc(coords, start=0, extent=90, style="arc", tags=tags),
            canvas.create_arc(coords, start=90, extent=90, style="arc", tags=tags),
            canvas.create_arc(coords, start=180, extent=90, style="arc", tags=tags),
            canvas.create_arc(coords, start=270, extent=90, style="arc", tags=tags),
    ]
```

Example of use:

```
box1 = Box(canvas, (100, 50, 200, 150))
box2 = Box(canvas, (100 + 100, 50, 200 + 100, 150))
```

To modify all arcs globally, you can configure the "arc" tag:

```
canvas.itemconfigure("arc", width=5, fill="yellow")
```

To modify a single box, use the tag for that box:

```
canvas.itemconfigure(box1.tag, outline='red')
```

To modify a single arc for a single box, use the index of that arc for that box

```
canvas.itemconfigure(box2.arcs[0], outline="green")
```

If you were to execute all of the above, the end result will look like the following image, where:

- yellow represents the changes we made to all arcs,
- red represents the changes we made to `box1`, and
- green represents the changes we made to a single arc in `box2`

[image: window screenshot]

If you want to be able to click on any single arc, you only have to have a single bind statement on the `"arc"` tag:

```
canvas.tag_bind("arc", "<Button-1>", bold)
```